# How to remove Dart DevTools?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying out Flutter with VS Code. Somehow, I ended up using (installed it by accident) Dart DevTools.

Whenever I run apps or start debugging apps, Dart DevTools pops up on a browser.

How can I remove/disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To **disable DevTools**:

Open VS Code settings and search for `Dart: Open Dev Tools` and set it to `never`. *(Removing `"dart.openDevTools": "flutter"` from settings.json should work too)*

To **uninstall/remove DevTools**, you can run:

- `pub global deactivate devtools` (if you have `pub` on your path)
- or `flutter pub global deactivate devtools` (if you have `flutter` on your path)

Comment: Removing the setting will cause it to pop up again so setting it to `never` may be more inline with the intention (though clicking "Never" on the popup will set this for you). Note: this only prevents it popping up, but does not remove/uninstall DevTools.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Settings and change the Open Dev Tools Settings to never. 
If asked after running the app, select Don't Ask again.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps

> First go to extension in Vs Code and select Dart extension
>
> Now click on setting Icon

[image]

> Now search `Dart: Dev Tools Port` in search bar
>
> Now click on setting icon of `Dart: Dev Tools Port`
>
> Then click on **Reset Setting**

[image]

For more information  please this documentation [Dart settings](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartopendevtools)

Comment: This setting only sets the port number that DevTools launches on - resetting it will not remove DevTools nor prevent it from opening automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this command :

```sh
flutter pub global deactivate devtools
```

Comment: If you've installed Flutter using the zip file, this might not work - as VS Code will register using `pub global activate` and not `flutter packages global activate`. If you install from a zip file, these two will have their own global package stores (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13248).

Answer (score 2):

The Dart extension activates using `pub`, so the correct way to remove it is:

```
pub global deactivate devtools
```

Using `flutter pub` may or may not work depending on whether you installed Flutter from the zip file (if you did, it will have its own list of activated packages, but VS Code always uses the default pub one).

If you just want to stop it opening when you run a project, you can instead just change the `"dart.openDevTools"` setting, which controls when DevTools will open automatically. If you set it to `never` then it will not open - nor will it prompt you to open it when you launch apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know better solution so I just deleted the files manually.
On Windows:

```
%LocalAppData%\Pub\Cache\bin\devtools.bat

%LocalAppData%\Pub\Cache\global_packages\devtools
```